# proplem saving excel as pdf on mac

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple file with VBA code that export sheet as pdf
i created the file on excel 365 on windows, but when tried to us it on mac (excel for mac 2015) it give me an error
here is the code:

```
Dim ID As String

ID = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1")
    Sheets("Sheet1 (2)").Select
    ChDir "D:\"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="D:\" + ID + ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
End Sub
```

as I mentioned it works well on windows but on mac not working, please any help

Comment: The path D:\ ... hardly exist on Linux (Mac)

Comment: Which line shows the error?